# Android - AlertDialog закрывается сам почти сразу после открытия

Tags: java, android

Метод *showResults* - показывает *AlertDialog*, метод *endOfGame* - закрывает *Aktivity*. При показе *AlertDialog* появляется на пол секунды, и потом исчезает, как оставить его на экране?

```
private void stopGame() {
    showResults();
    endOfGame();
}

private void showResults() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.results);
    builder.setMessage("Message");
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.OK, null);
    builder.create().show();
}
```

В метод `stopGame()` приложение попадает из *AsyncTask*, возможно где-то здесь ошибка?

```
private class TimerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
    private int time;

    public TimerAsyncTask(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (time > 0) {
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            time--;
            publishProgress(time);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        chronometrView.setText(values[0].toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        stopGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: С кодом все ок, больше интересует что у вас происходит в endOfGame();

Comment: Диалог привязан к создающей его активити. Закрывайте ее когда пользователь выйдет из диалога.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Присоединюсь к комментарию  Abrog Petrovich.

В методе  `showResults()` вы вызываете билдер для создания диалогового окна. 
Строчка `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` по сути говорит, что билдер будет использовать данное активити (инфлейтить его, использовать стиль и тд), те вы создаете диалоговое окно относительно данного активити.

Но вы в `endOfGame();` я так понимаю закрываете это активити, и закрывается диалог - соответственно. В голову приходят срау два способа решения:

1.Действительно, переместите закрытие Activity те ваш метод endOfGame(); в AlertDialog, пусть срабатывает при его закрытии например, ну или сделайте логику Да/Нет. Дайте пользователю принять выбор.

2.Можете создавать Диалоговое окно в новом Acitivity, или открывать новое Actvity в форме диалогового окна, вариантов здесь много, но нужно видеть что происходит в методе endOfGame().

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Правильно ли я понял, получается что AlertDialog создается в новом потоке?

Comment: Здесь не идет речь о потоках, здесь прямая работа класса Dialog, а точней его подкласса AlertDialog. Прямая визуализация диалогового окна, зависимого от параметров Activity, вызываемого из Context. Всё в основном потоке. Просто если вы закрываете Activity, а у вас открыт диалог - созданный этим Activity, оно тоже закроется - это логично.